# Deleting strings with Sed regex

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I would like to do a string replacement on the command line.  I can do this in Python, but it would be easier for my workflow if I just do this in Unix.  Currently I'm trying to get this to work with `sed`.

I am trying to delete any information surrounded by single quotes.  Inside the quotes, I have varying combinations of letters, numbers, spaces, dashes, square brackets, underscores, and semicolons.

Here's an example...

```
(214016:0.13461,814430:0.04526)'o__stuff; f__[morestuff-123]':0.03063
```

In python, I can do this...

```
line = "(214016:0.13461,814430:0.04526)'o__stuff; f__[morestuff-123]':0.03063"
sub(r"\'[ \w;\-\[\]]+\'","",line)
```

Which correctly prints...

```
(214016:0.13461,814430:0.04526):0.03063
```

I'm now trying to do this with `sed`, which hasn't worked out for me so far.  I've been trying to work with [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm), which has been helpful.  Here's what I've got...

```
sed "s/\'[-[:alnum:] ;\[\]]+\'//g" file.txt
```

This doesn't work.  Any thoughts on what is wrong?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As I see, space is missing from the `[]`, isn't it?

Comment: Minor issue: do not use `cat file | sed ...`! Use `sed ... file` instead!

Comment: that's true, i'll add that.  however, it's still not working...  thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/'\''[^'\'']*'\''//g' file
```

N.B. the expression `'\''` is a shell device to represent a single `'`

```
sed "s/'[^']*'//g" file
```

works too.

Comment: thanks potong, both work perfectly!  i'm new to regex...  i'm guessing `[^']` specifies "match any character except for the single quote', and then it's specific because it's looking for targets surrounded by single quotes

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the dash first or last in the regex; a dash between two characters defines a character range, even when one of them is a backslash.

Similarly, to match a literal right square bracket, put it first (after any negation or dash). In traditional regex, a backslash is just a literal backslash in a character range, and you disambiguate by putting any special characters (dash, square brackets) first or last.

Oh, and lose the [Useless Use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html);

```
sed "s/\'[-][[:alnum:];]+\'//g" file.txt
```

Do you really need to replace multiple occurrences per line? If not, the `/g` flag is superfluous (but mostly harmless).

Comment: thanks, that fixed the invalid character range error.  i'll take that part out of the question.

Comment: Please don't change the question except to clarify it. Maybe this was a borderline case un that respect.

Comment: Dar, still doesn't work.  Yes, this is a single line with about 100 instances of the pattern, so the /g is useful.  Duly noted about editing.

Comment: `sed "s/\'[-[A-Za-z0-9_ ;]*//g` works, but then when i try to add the square brackets it fails...

Comment: wait, i'm not sure why, but `sed "s/\'[-[A-Za-z0-9_ ;]*//g` gets rid of the square brackets.  so this would be the answer...

Comment: actually, it only gets rid of the forward bracket.  and it only stops because there is a : following the pattern, which is not in my search